# In Qt/QML, how to load different images for different device densities (Android)

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm using Qt 5.4 and Qt Creator 3.3.2.

Loading different images, depending on the current OS, can be done with

```
Image {source: "logo.png"   }
```

and the following resources

```
logo.png
+windows/logo.png
+android/logo.png
+ios/logo.png
```

If I understand the documentation correctly, adding

```
+ios/logo.png
+ios/logo@2x.png
+ios/logo@3x.png
```

will, on iOS, select different images based on the device density.

Can I use a similar mechanism to load different images for different Android dpi's (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, ...).  If so, how should the directory structure look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Image {source: "logo" + density + ".png" }
```

And `density` can for example be S, M, L and you have `logoS.png`, `logoM.png` and `logoL.png`. Or you can use it to specify different path rather than image name. Either way.

You can use `QScreen`'s `logicalDotsPerInch` property and expose that to QML to determine the value for `density`.

Also, if images are sufficiently big, you can actually get away with only shipping the larger version and scaling it down as needed. It will be easier and you will not be limited to particular sizes.

Comment: I see where you're going. I'm not sure though how this works out when both iOS and Android have to be supported. Drawback of this approach is also that it moves the responsibility [of selecting the correct image] to the QML application (whereas for OS-dependent images or iOS-densities, the underlying QFileSelector seems to manage this).

Comment: That's the thing about it - it will work on every OS, it is not a platform specific solution, so it will work everywhere. It doesn't really matter who does it, the point is to have it done. You can wrap an `Image` in your own component, and implement the path modification to be more transparent, using a QML singleton, if you so chose.

Comment: Good point! So the idea is to only have this approach (and not, as I understood it first, to use your approach for Android and the existing approaches for iOS). It's a pity though that the Qt built-in support seems to be almost complete but not really useable yet.

Comment: @MarcVanDaele - IMO this is something trivial to do yourself, dedicated support for it is not really needed. Plus you can always tweak and make exceptions to your own implementation scheme, while with using something "stock" you are left with the default behavior, which may not always suit you. Just put different DPI images in different folders, and append the appropriate prefix to the `source` string.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate ppi using `Screen.pixelDensity` QML property and assign different images for different ranges of ppi. A sample code could be found in this [KDAB blog post](http://www.kdab.com/borderimage-scaling-scalable-uis-2-2/) :

```
property int ppi: Screen.pixelDensity*25.4 

property var dir: ["MDPI","HDPI","XHDPI","XXHDPI",
                                    "XXXHDPI","XXXXHDPI"]
readonly property int ppiRange:{ 
 if (ppi>=540)
  5
 else if (ppi>=360)
  4
 else if (ppi>=270)
  3
 else if (ppi>=180)
  2
 else if (ppi>=135)
  1
 else
  0
 }

BorderImage {
   id: scalableElement3
   source: "./Images/" + dir[ppiRange] + "/image.png"
   width: parent.width-ppi/2
   height: ppi*1.5
   anchors.centerIn: parent
   border.left: 0.3*ppi; border.top: 0.3*ppi
   border.right: 0.18*ppi; border.bottom: 0.18*ppi
 }
```